# Ошибка в сборке Gradle

Tags: android, unity3d

Ошибка

> Error:Execution failed for task > ':transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
> >     copied in APK lib/armeabi-v7a/libApp.so       File1:
> >     C:\Users\Adren.android\build-cache\cf2076a8b01646c8b892a28e60cc565a8554720d\output\jni
> >       File2:
> >     E:\ADropHunt\DropHunt10\Export\DropHunt\DropHunt\firebase-app-unity-4.2.0\build\intermediates\bundles\default\jni

Из советов интернета пробовал вставить, не помогло

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libfb.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libfb.so'
}
```

gradle:

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'firebase-analytics-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-analytics-impl-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-analytics-unity-4.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-app-unity-4.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-games-plugin-support', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-ads-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-ads-lite-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-analytics-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-analytics-impl-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-auth-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-auth-base-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-base-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-basement-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-drive-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-games-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-gass-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-location-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-nearby-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-tasks-11.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'runtime-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-compat-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-core-ui-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-core-utils-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-fragment-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-media-compat-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-v4-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile project(':adcolony-sdk')
    compile project(':appodeal')
    compile project(':Firebase')
    compile project(':firebase-analytics-unity-4.2.0')
    compile project(':firebase-app-unity-4.2.0')
    compile project(':firebase-common-11.4.2')
    compile project(':firebase-core-11.4.2')
    compile project(':firebase-iid-11.4.2')
    compile project(':GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin')
    compile project(':inmobi')
    compile project(':mmedia')
    compile project(':mobvista_alphab')
    compile project(':mobvista_appwall')
    compile project(':mobvista_appwallext')
    compile project(':mobvista_common')
    compile project(':mobvista_interstitial')
    compile project(':mobvista_mvdownloads')
    compile project(':mobvista_mvjscommon')
    compile project(':mobvista_mvnative')
    compile project(':mobvista_nativeex')
    compile project(':mobvista_offerwall')
    compile project(':mobvista_playercommon')
    compile project(':mobvista_reward')
    compile project(':mobvista_videocommon')
    compile project(':mobvista_videofeeds')
    compile project(':ogury')
    compile project(':play-services-analytics-impl-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':play-services-analytics-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':play-services-base-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':play-services-basement-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':play-services-tasks-license-11.4.2')
    compile project(':startapp')
    compile project(':yandex-metrica')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 27
        applicationId 'com.-.-'
            multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb','bin/data/63f4aa33326196a458b1aa87c81ffb81.resource','bin/data/sharedassets1.resource','bin/data/sharedassets2.resource','bin/data/sharedassets3.resource','bin/data/sharedassets4.resource'
    }

    signingConfigs { release {
        storeFile file('E:/-/-/TOOLS/user.keystore')
        storePassword '-'
        keyAlias '-'
        keyPassword '-'
    } }

buildTypes {
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дубликаты были в пакетах, удалил подключение и ошибка исчезла

```
compile project(':firebase-analytics-unity-4.2.0')
compile project(':firebase-app-unity-4.2.0')
compile project(':firebase-common-11.4.2')
compile project(':firebase-core-11.4.2')
compile project(':firebase-iid-11.4.2')
```